# GridView doesn't load images of first visible set

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I have GridView and I load different views depending on item position:

```
@Override
public View getView(int _i, View _view, ViewGroup viewGroup){
    BlockMod _b = (BlockMod)getItem(_i);
    if(_b.getType().equals(BlockMod.BLOCK_TYPE_NOTE))
        _view = new BlockViewNote(getActivity(),gridView.getColumnWidth(), _b);
    if(_b.getType().equals(BlockMod.BLOCK_TYPE_IMAGE))
        _view = new BlockViewImage(getActivity(),gridView.getColumnWidth(), _b);
    if(_b.getType().equals(BlockMod.BLOCK_TYPE_STATUS))
        _view = new BlockViewStatus(getActivity(),gridView.getColumnWidth());
    return _view;
}
```

Inside of these views I load some remote image:

```
public BlockViewImage(Context context, int _columnWidth, BlockMod _block){
    super(context);
    block = _block;
    rootView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.story_block_image,this);
    AbsListView.LayoutParams _lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(_columnWidth,_columnWidth);
    this.setLayoutParams(_lp);
    ImageSize targetSize = new ImageSize(_columnWidth, _columnWidth);
    final ImageView _background = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.storyBlockImageBackground);
    DisplayImageOptions _imageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(block.getImageSmall(), targetSize, _imageOptions , new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage){
            _background.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is it won't load images for any of initial views, If I scroll down it will load all images for next views. And if I scroll back up it will load images for previous ones. But never loads on it's own without scrolling.

If I use different library for images then it works just fine:

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(block.getImageSmall())
                .into(_background);
```

Code for full Fragment class:

```
package net.eq.pck.fragments.main.story;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import net.eq.pck.*;
import net.eq.pck.compoundViews.CustomGridView;
import net.eq.pck.fragments.main.story.blocks.*;
import net.eq.pck.model.block.BlockMod;
import net.eq.pck.model.stories.StoryMod;
import net.eq.pck.server.Scheduler;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by usr on 1/21/14.
 */
public class StoryFragment2 extends Fragment{

    private StoryMod story;

    private View rootView;
    private CustomGridView gridView;
    private CustomAdapter gridAdapter;

    public void setStory(StoryMod _story){
        story = _story;
    }

    public interface StoryFragmentInterface{
        void onBack();
    }

    public StoryFragment2(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_fragment, container, false);
        Scheduler.getInstance().scheduleStoryUpdate(story);
        gridView = getViewGrid();
        gridAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        return rootView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    }

    private CustomGridView getViewGrid(){
        return (CustomGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.storyFragmentGridView);
    }

    private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private HashMap<Integer,View> customCash = new HashMap<Integer, View>();

        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return story.getBlocks().length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position){
            return story.getBlocks()[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position){
            return 0;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int _i, View _view, ViewGroup viewGroup){
            BlockMod _b = (BlockMod)getItem(_i);

            if(customCash.containsKey(_i))
                return customCash.get(_i);

            if(_b.getType().equals(BlockMod.BLOCK_TYPE_NOTE))
                _view = new BlockViewNote(getActivity(),gridView.getColumnWidth(), _b);
            if(_b.getType().equals(BlockMod.BLOCK_TYPE_IMAGE))
                _view = new BlockViewImage(getActivity(),gridView.getColumnWidth(), _b);
            if(_b.getType().equals(BlockMod.BLOCK_TYPE_STATUS))
                _view = new BlockViewStatus(getActivity(),gridView.getColumnWidth());

            customCash.put(_i,_view);
            return _view;
        }

    }

}
```

CustomGridView:

```
public class CustomGridView extends GridView{
    public CustomGridView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }



    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public int getColumnWidth(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) return super.getColumnWidth();
        else{
            try{
                Field field = GridView.class.getDeclaredField("mColumnWidth");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Integer value = (Integer) field.get(this);
                field.setAccessible(false);
                return value.intValue();
            }catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }catch(IllegalAccessException e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your activity code please?

Comment: Here you go, edit with complete code

Comment: Thanks, the CustomGridView class also would be helpful

Comment: It's almost everything there. That class extends FrameLayout and has only constructor that I included

Comment: In that case have you tried using a standard GridView?

Comment: Uh sorry, I thought you asked for other class. My Custom grid view just has overwrite for "getColumvWidth" I'll include it right away

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49252/discussion-between-tpbapp-and-somerandomusername)

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because you're not setting the adapter in onCreateView?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_fragment, container, false);
    Scheduler.getInstance().scheduleStoryUpdate(story);
    gridView = getViewGrid();
    gridAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: How would this be different from doing it in onCreateView, except I don't have layout inflater there?